# how to link blade.php page to home page option in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner in laravel and have made one frontend page as blade.php
But not getting how to see the output on browser.
Is there any other code which I have to add.

Comment: Hello SHWETA SHINDE! welcome to Stack Overflow. The point of the sight is to create a library of knowledge, without any "debug/write my code" questions. In light of that, could you please tell us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your blade file has name `resources/views/index.blade.php`, you need to add this code to file `routes/web.php`:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

Comment: And then on browser should I pass http://localhost:8000/index

Comment: Run in terminal `php artisan serve` then open in browser `http://127.0.0.1:8000`